# Flask Syntax Error: Non-ASCII character '\xe2'

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm new to Flask and I'm trying to go through introductory tutorials(
[here](https://medium.com/python-flask-django-tutorials-and-tips/how-to-build-a-crud-application-using-flask-python-framework-3a398b04c3c6#.4dyxuki3w) ). I simply copy and paste the code and do the steps

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file main.py on line 8, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Indeed, I opened the link in the error and googled the error and checked few search items but I didn't get the clue.

It looks lie there is a problem with the syntax of this line

```
app.config[‘SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI’] = ‘sqlite:///’ + os.path.join(basedir, ‘app.sqlite’)
```

My whole purpose is getting intoduced on how to use Flask and to CURD operation using SQLite database.

Comment: Please, could you post code sample we could check…

Comment: Problems with copying from online code - character encoding. If you typed out the command, it might have worked correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the unicode character "right single quotation mark" (‘) as per http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm

If you change this to use a normal single quote, it should work.

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.sqlite')
```

Comment: I agree: quotes come from the original blog post.